# Transfer files between servers without downloading and uploading

Tags: macos, ftp, terminal

I need to get one (huge) file from one server to another and I have a slow Internet connection. I tried using Transmit, the ftp program, but I believe it's downloading the file and uploading it to the other server.

So, is there a way to move it directly from one server to the other, either using and ftp client or the Mac terminal, without having to download and upload the file?

Comment: Belongs to http://superuser.com/ . In general, FTP supports server-to-server transfer, so your task should be possible.

Comment: Really? How do yo do it? Do you know an application or script that can do it? I tried googling but had no success.

Comment: http://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/what-is-fxp-f14.html , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol

Answer (score 0):

If you have shell access to one of the servers, simply login to that server using telnet or ssh.  Start a simple ftp client in the shell and log into the other server.  Use a basic ftp command (put or get) to copy the file. Usually though, sysadmins are likely to make shell access difficult.

If you have no shell access, but you do have a webserver with PHP, then the easiest is to write a simple PHP program to do the job.  Upload it and trigger it from a browser.  Here's one I wrote:

```
<?php
// qdftp.php - Quick & Dirty FTP 
// Place this script in a web accessible
// folder alongside the file you want to send,
// then invoke it from a browser.
//===============================
$server = "123.123.123.123"; //target server address or domain name
$user   = "username"; //username on target server
$pass   = "password"; //password on target server
$file   = "myfile.zip"; //source file
//================================
$sessid = ftp_connect($server); //connect
$login_ok = ftp_login($sessid, $user, "$pass"); //login
if ((!$sessid) || (!$login_ok)):
    echo "failed to connect: check hostname, username & password";
    exit; //failed? bail!
endif;
$xfer = ftp_put($sessid, $file, $file, FTP_BINARY);  //transfer
echo "file transfer " . ($xfer)? "succeded" : "failed" ;
ftp_close($sessid);
?>
```

Then trigger it from your browser

```
http://mysourceserver.com/qdftp.php
```

Last thing: delete qdftp.php when you're done - it's got your userename and password!

Answer (score -1):

The FTP protocol does not support 3rd-party transfers like this.  You might try:

```
$ scp host1:file host2:file2
```

But I don’t know how that’s implemented.  It might bounce everything through you again, which is what you’re trying to avoid. That is, I suspect that it does this, which routes everything through your local pipe:

```
$ (ssh host1 "cat <file") | (ssh host2 "cat >file")
```

But you really want:

```
$ ssh host1 "scp file host2:"
```